# Build Expression Equals on string

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, expression

The code below works with `StartsWith` and `Contains` but when I tried `Equals` I get this exception : *More than one method 'Equals' on type 'System.String' is compatible with the supplied arguments*.

To resume, the CreatePredicate can build 3 types of predicate but only the `Equals` does not work :

- `AList.Where(x => x.MyField.StartsWith("ValueToSearch")); //OK`
- `AList.Where(x => x.MyField.Contains("ValueToSearch"));   //OK`
- `AList.Where(x => x.MyField.Equals("ValueToSearch"));     //Not OK`

..

```
public enum TypeSearch
        {
            StartsWith = 1,
            Contains = 2,
            Equals = 3
        }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreatePredicate<T>(string member, object value, TypeSearch type)
    {
        var p = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body = p;
        foreach (var subMember in member.Split('.'))
        {
            body = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(body, subMember);
        }

        var res = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(
                        body,
                        "ToUpper", null),
                    type.ToString(), null,
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(value.ToString().ToUpper())
                ), p);

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you pass the MethodInfo?

Comment: MethodeInfo .... how can I do this, not a specialist in Expression.

Answer (score 10):

As the error message explains, there is more than one `Equals` method defined on the `string` type - [`Equals(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fkfd9eh8.aspx) and [`Equals(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/858x0yyx.aspx). Since you are only using the name to locate the method you want, the match is ambiguous.

One solution is to pass the `MethodInfo` for the method to `Expression.Call` e.g.

```
MethodInfo equalsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
Expression.Call(instanceExpr, equalsMethod, Expression.Constant(value.ToString().ToUpper()));
```